# cannot set property of 'onkeydown' of null

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, events, event-handling

I am getting error  "cannot set property of 'onkeydown' of null"  for the following code.

Please anybody can suggest why am I getting this error

```js
document.getElementById('customerId').onkeydown = function(evt) {
  debugger
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
  var enterkey = (keyCode == 13);
  if (enterkey) {
    var customerCode = $('#customerId').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/Home/addTaxNotice",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        value: customerCode
      }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data) {}
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="customerId" maxlength="6" />
```

Comment: it seems that the element selector did not find the tag with a given id, could you tell us where did you place the script tag? it may be order issue, where script is triggered before the tag is added to the body

Comment: Since the snippet I made you does not give the error, I expect the dupe gives you the answer

Comment: <html>
<head></head>
<body>
     //input code goes here
</body>
</html>
<script>
     // here i have added code to check if enter is hit
</script>

Comment: I added an onclick function in the input tag and added all script code inside function and its working for me know.
Thank you for reverting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `document.getElementById('customerId').onkeydown`, probably you entered either wrong id of your element, or your element does not exist, or hasn't been created yet.